# Upgrade Imagick from 3.5.1 to 3.6.0 on Centos7

Tags: imagemagick, centos7

i'm trying to update imagick module version from version 3.5.1 https://ibb.co/3hJXmtW to latest 3.6
For doing this i start reading documentation "Install Howto" here https://centos.pkgs.org/7/remi-x86_64/php-pecl-imagick-im6-3.6.0-1.el7.remi.5.4.x86_64.rpm.html
Here the result of first step: https://ibb.co/TcwjYR3
This is the result of second step: https://ibb.co/xFN1wN3
I'm following the correct documentation?
Thanks

Comment: Please paste the text in your question instead of using link to image....

Answer (score 1):

For a proper configuration of the repository, simply follow the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions.

In your 1st step, you download the repository home page, which does not make sense.

Notice: you have the choice between

- **php-pecl-imagick-im6** which use ImageMagick version 6
- **php-pecl-imagick-im7** which use ImageMagick version 7

Provided APIs are slightly different

- some methods are deprecated with IM6 and removed with IM7
- additional methods available with IM7

P.S. yum install **php-imagick** (as explained by the wizard for all extensions) will work and install the better candidate.

Comment: I got following result... No package php-imagick available. '[root@server ~]# yum install php-imagick
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.prometeus.net
 * epel: mirror.nextlayer.at
 * extras: mirrors.prometeus.net
 * remi: mirror.23m.com
 * remi-php55: mirror.23m.com
 * remi-php56: mirror.23m.com
 * remi-php70: mirror.23m.com
 * remi-php74: mirror.23m.com
 * remi-safe: mirror.23m.com
 * updates: mirrors.prometeus.net
No package php-imagick available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@server ~]#'

Comment: Should work.BTW why have you enabled all versions ? one should be enough. Also check "exclude" from yum.conf (especially on some panel altered distro)